# C++23 std::ranges::enumerate with custom index type

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

C++23 introduces the new long awaited [`std::ranges::views::enumerate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/enumerate_view) which when iterated over, returns an iterator that dereferences to a tuple of the index and a reference to the element (of the underlying range/view) at that index.

[This](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.enumerate.iterator) seems to say that the index type is specified to be `range_difference_t<Base>`.

My question:
**Is it possible to define a custom index type that enumerate would produce?
If not, what other options do I have?**

An example use-case that I'm working with is a custom Vector implementation that only allows `operator[]` and `at()` to work with a custom "strong" type. Where the strong type is a wrapper around a base integer type but disallows implicit construction from or implicit conversion to its base integer type.

```cpp
template <class T, class Tag>
struct StrongT {
    explicit StrongT(T t) : _t(t) {} // note the "explicit"
    
    T base() const { return t; }  // note that this is not a conversion operator 

    /// ... define all neccessary arithmetic operators

private:
    T _t;
};

using MyIdx =  StrongT<int, struct MyTag>;

using MyVec = StrongVector<std::string, MyIdx>

int main () {
    MyVec v {"hello", "world"};
    for ( auto [idx, str] : v | std::ranges::enumerate ) {
        assert(v[idx] == str); // doesn't work because `decltype(idx)` is not `MyIdx`
    }
}
```

Edit: the *iterator* to my custom vector still has `operator[]` defined to work with `iter_difference_t` as would be expected by algorithms.

Comment: "*I'm working with is a custom Vector implementation that only allows operator[] and at() to work with a custom "strong" type.*" If you do that to the `operator[]` on the iterator, then it will not be a [proper `random_access_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/random_access_iterator). The `[]` on the iterator *must* take an `iter_difference_t`. So unless this type is implicitly convertible from an `iter_difference_t`, it won't count as a `random_access_iterator`.

Comment: the iterator can still take `iter_difference_t` but operator[] of the custom vector itself only takes `StrongT`

Comment: That sounds very incoherent. `range[i]` and `range.begin()[i]` ought to do the same thing if the range offers `[]` functionality. The standard may not require it, but users will *expect* it. But if you want to do that, you should update your question to make it clear that you're fine with the range interface using a different `[]` interface from the iterator `[]` interface.

Comment: fwiw, `iterator::operator[]` also has an overload that works with the strong type but that's not entirely helpful to algorithms which is why I put back in the overload that work with  `iter_difference_t` _but_ only for the iterator.

Answer (score 2):

You could only theoretically do this by making your iterator use this other class as a difference type. But you can't really do that. [[iterator.requirements.general] tells us](https://For%20every%20iterator%20type%20X,%20there%20is%20a%20corresponding%20signed%20integer-like%20type%20(%5Biterator.concept.winc%5D)%20called%20the%20difference%20type%20of%20the%20iterator.) the requirements for a difference type:

> For every iterator type X, there is a corresponding signed integer-like type ([[iterator.concept.winc]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/iterator.requirements#iterator.concept.winc)) called the difference type of the iterator.

And that link tells us that there are two kinds of integer-like types: actual integers and integer-class types, as defined below:

> A type I is an integer-class type if it is in a set of implementation-defined types that behave as integer types do, as defined below.

Only the implementation can define the set of "integer-class types", so you cannot define a class that is a part of that set. Therefore, if you set your iterator's difference type to match the type you want to use, then you have broken the requirements of the iterator. And thus, you get UB.

If you absolutely must do this, you'll have to make your own version of `enumerate`.

Comment: damn thats the same conclusion I came to due to the requirement of "integer-like" type for difference type... I was wondering what other options or ideas others might have to do this or something similar to this.

Comment: I wonder why integer-like is so narrowly defined.

Comment: @supernun: Even if they did define "integer-like" more broadly, that definition would undoubtedly include being convertible from/to integers.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply transform the index to your desired type:

```cpp
for ( auto [idx, str] : v
      | std::views::enumerate
      | std::views::transform([]<class Idx, class Ref>(std::tuple<Idx, Ref> tp) {
          return std::tuple<MyIdx, Ref>(MyIdx(std::get<0>(tp)), std::get<1>(tp));
      })) {
    assert(v[idx] == str);
}
```

Or for your `for` loop, just construct it in the body:

```cpp
for ( auto [idx_, str] : v | std::ranges::enumerate ) {
    MyIdx idx(idx_);
    assert(v[idx] == str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since enumerate takes only one range argument, I don't see how it can be informed that it needs to generate an index type other than the range's difference_type.

What you can do is combine `iota` with `zip` to get a similar effect.

```
#include<ranges>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

template<class Index, class Range>
auto my_enumerate(Range&& rng) {
    return std::views::zip(std::views::iota(static_cast<Index>(0)), rng);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<char> const v = {'A', 'B', 'C'};

    auto const& m = my_enumerate<unsigned int>(v); //  | std::views::enumerate;
 
    for (auto const [key, value] : m)
        std::cout << '[' << key << "]:" << value << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ozvescT6T

Exercise for the reader: make it pippable `v | my_enumerate`.

Comment: `zip` with `iota` has the downside that it's no longer a `sized_range` (because unbounded `iota` isn't a sized range), so some optimizations don't happen and things like `m.back()` don't work. Fixed with `if constexpr (std::ranges::sized_range<Range>) return std::views::zip(std::views::iota(Index(0), Index(std::ranges::size(rng))), rng); else`. But this leads to more inefficiencies (where the size has to be stored twice)

Comment: @Artyer. Good points. I think this could be a defect of zip, in principle it can deduce a combination of an infinite range and and a sized range is sized.